# Bootstrap Fluid Rows Overlap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the current code running while including the standard and responsive css of the latest Bootstrap.

I cannot understand why when I increase the font size the row does not respond at all and the text is currently overlapping.

Any advice would help as I am new to Bootstrap. Also I know this is hacky but it was a quick an easy way to test my idea.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12" style=" text-align:center;">
        <p style="font-size:6em;  font-weight:bold;">LARGE TEXT</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12" style="text-align:center; font-size:3em; font-weight:bold;">
        <p>Date 02/02/2013</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the line height of your `p` element. The line height is inherited from the body specification, which by default is set to 20px.

Changing your style to `style="font-size:6em; line-height:normal; font-weight:bold;"` should do the trick.

See http://jsfiddle.net/7EXmD/1/.

I wouldn't recommend styling your elements this way for production use, but as you say, for testing, this is how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The row doesn't respond to the text size, the row responds to the size of the browser window. If you are using responsive layout you should consider using `@media query` to size down the text so that it fits appropriately as everything should scale down not just the containing spans.